# sum of multiple columns using group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I want to calculate the sum in multiple columns with the group_by function. I want to group by the columns `Gebied` and `Datum` and calculate the sum in the columns `Som van vangtuigen` and `Som van Aantal`. I used the following code, but this didn't work out for me:

```
library(tidyverse)
CPUE_deelgebied_totaal <- CPUE_deelgebied %>%
  group_by(Gebied, Datum) %>%
  summarise_at(c(`Som vangtuigen`, `Som van Aantal`), sum)
```

df = CPUE_deelgebied:

```
structure(list(Soort = c("Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Geknobbelde Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", "Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft", 
"Rode Amerikaanse rivierkreeft"), Gebied = c("Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", 
"Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "Oost", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West"), `Deel gebied` = c("21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", 
"21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", 
"21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", 
"21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", 
"21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", 
"21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", 
"21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", 
"21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_DV", 
"21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", 
"21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "22_OOST_D", 
"21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", 
"21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", 
"21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_A", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", 
"21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", 
"21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_B", "21_OOST_C", 
"21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", 
"21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_C", 
"21_OOST_C", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", 
"21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", 
"21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_DV", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", "21_OOST_EXTRA", 
"21_OOST_EXTRA", "22_OOST_D", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", 
"21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", 
"21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", 
"21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", 
"21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", 
"21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", 
"21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_E", 
"21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", 
"21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", 
"21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", 
"21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", 
"21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_A", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", "21_WEST_B", 
"21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", 
"21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", 
"21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_C", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", 
"21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", 
"21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_D", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", 
"21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", 
"21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E", "21_WEST_E"
), Datum = structure(c(18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 
18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 
18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 
18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 
18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 
18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 
18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 
18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 
19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 
18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 
18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 
18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 
19006, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 
18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 
18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 
18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 
19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 
18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 
18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 
18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 
18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 
18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 
18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 
18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055, 
18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 18894, 18929, 
19006, 19055, 18683, 18711, 18754, 18780, 18803, 18831, 18866, 
18894, 18929, 18954, 19006, 19055), class = "Date"), `Som vangtuigen` = c(12, 
12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 10, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 10, 12, 
10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), `Som nachten` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), `Som van Aantal` = c(10, 11, 5, 7, 12.42, 12, 46, 47.88, 40.18, 
19, 6, 6.51, 18, 7, 9, 24, 20.04, 18, 32, 49, 41.22, 35.04, 15, 
17.1, 14, 7, 7, 39, 18.9, 19, 11, 19, 17.57, 6, 1, 3.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
55, 50, 22, 51, 35.19, 34, 30, 37.62, 43.05, 22, 7, 45.57, 111, 
97, 39, 39, 63.46, 26, 41, 38.5, 25.19, 26.28, 16, 43.7, 51.99, 
46, 10, 22, 31.5, 21, 29, 18, 72.79, 11, 5, 40.25, 57, 28, 27, 
43, 45.6, 33, 86.45, 66.67, 16, 16, 14, 4, 21, 20, 20, 29, 50, 
20, 58, 8, 16, 14, 75.24, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2.55, 37, 45, 27, 47, 25, 
4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 7, 5.6, 8, 5, 9, 5, 8, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 33.15, 
16, 13, 6, 12, 4, 5, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4.76, 7, 5, 22, 1, 0, 0, 
12, 7, 5, 16, 23, 9, 94, 81.25, 32, 8, 4, 0, 38, 50.01, 29, 31, 
53.55, 24, 18, 7, 6, 3, 4, 3, 91.99, 94, 44, 64, 86.8, 26, 24, 
15, 27, 38, 17, 27, 64, 55, 12, 13, 15.3, 13, 9, 1, 5, 4, 1, 
3, 0, 22, 11, 43, 49.98, 32, 21, 17, 3, 8, 6, 16, 23, 11, 12, 
4, 1, 5, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1), CPUE = c(0.833333333333333, 0.916666666666667, 
0.454545454545455, 0.583333333333333, 1.12909090909091, 1, 3.83333333333333, 
3.99, 3.34833333333333, 1.58333333333333, 0.5, 0.5425, 1.5, 0.583333333333333, 
0.818181818181818, 2, 1.67, 1.5, 2.66666666666667, 4.08333333333333, 
3.435, 2.92, 1.25, 1.425, 1.16666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.636363636363636, 3.25, 1.71818181818182, 1.58333333333333, 
0.916666666666667, 1.9, 1.59727272727273, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.291666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.58333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
2, 4.25, 3.19909090909091, 2.83333333333333, 2.5, 3.135, 3.5875, 
1.83333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 3.7975, 9.25, 8.08333333333333, 
3.54545454545455, 3.25, 5.28833333333333, 2.16666666666667, 3.41666666666667, 
3.20833333333333, 2.09916666666667, 2.19, 1.33333333333333, 3.64166666666667, 
4.3325, 3.83333333333333, 0.909090909090909, 1.83333333333333, 
2.86363636363636, 1.75, 2.41666666666667, 1.8, 6.61727272727273, 
0.916666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 3.35416666666667, 4.75, 
2.33333333333333, 2.45454545454545, 3.58333333333333, 3.8, 2.75, 
7.20416666666667, 5.55583333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
1.16666666666667, 2, 10.5, 10, 10, 14.5, 25, 10, 29, 4, 8, 7, 
6.27, 0.416666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.545454545454545, 
0.583333333333333, 0.2125, 3.08333333333333, 3.75, 2.25, 3.91666666666667, 
2.08333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.272727272727273, 0.583333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.75, 0.416666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.25, 0.0833333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0909090909090909, 0.5, 2.7625, 1.6, 1.08333333333333, 
0.6, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.0833333333333333, 0, 0, 0.396666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0, 0, 
1, 0.583333333333333, 0.454545454545455, 1.33333333333333, 2.09090909090909, 
0.75, 7.83333333333333, 6.77083333333333, 2.66666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0, 3.16666666666667, 4.1675, 2.63636363636364, 
2.58333333333333, 4.4625, 2, 1.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 
0.333333333333333, 0.25, 7.66583333333333, 7.83333333333333, 
4, 5.33333333333333, 7.23333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 2, 1.25, 
2.25, 3.16666666666667, 1.41666666666667, 2.25, 5.33333333333333, 
4.58333333333333, 1.09090909090909, 1.08333333333333, 1.275, 
1.3, 0.75, 0.1, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.25, 0, 1.83333333333333, 0.916666666666667, 3.58333333333333, 
4.165, 2.66666666666667, 1.75, 1.41666666666667, 0.25, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 1.33333333333333, 1.91666666666667, 1, 1, 0.363636363636364, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0, 0.416666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.0833333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-236L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across()` inside `summarise` instead of `summarise_at`.

From `?summarize_at` we can see that:

> Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb. See vignette("colwise") for details.

```
library(dplyr)

CPUE_deelgebied %>% 
  group_by(Gebied, Datum) %>%
  summarise(across(c(`Som vangtuigen`, `Som van Aantal`), sum))

# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   Gebied [2]
   Gebied Datum      `Som vangtuigen` `Som van Aantal`
   <chr>  <date>                <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Oost   2021-02-25              100             321.
 2 Oost   2021-03-25              100             267 
 3 Oost   2021-05-07               92             139 
 4 Oost   2021-06-02              100             245 
 5 Oost   2021-06-25               96             256.
 6 Oost   2021-07-23              100             213 
 7 Oost   2021-08-27              100             295.
 8 Oost   2021-09-24               96             335.
 9 Oost   2021-10-29               98             264 
10 Oost   2021-11-23              100             151.
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Comment: This is exactly how it should be. However i got the following error message: Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @Pepijn95 Maybe you are using `summarise` from another package, try `dplyr::summarise`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it didn't work was because it needs to be wrapped in `vars`

```
library(dplyr)
CPUE_deelgebied %>%
  group_by(Gebied, Datum) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(c(`Som vangtuigen`, `Som van Aantal`)), sum)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 4
# Groups:   Gebied [2]
   Gebied Datum      `Som vangtuigen` `Som van Aantal`
   <chr>  <date>                <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Oost   2021-02-25              100             321.
 2 Oost   2021-03-25              100             267 
 3 Oost   2021-05-07               92             139 
 4 Oost   2021-06-02              100             245 
 5 Oost   2021-06-25               96             256.
 6 Oost   2021-07-23              100             213 
 7 Oost   2021-08-27              100             295.
 8 Oost   2021-09-24               96             335.
 9 Oost   2021-10-29               98             264 
10 Oost   2021-11-23              100             151.
# … with 14 more rows
```

---

Or instead of backquote, use the normal quotes

```
CPUE_deelgebied %>%
  group_by(Gebied, Datum) %>%
  summarise_at(.vars = c("Som vangtuigen", "Som van Aantal"), sum)
# A tibble: 24 × 4
# Groups:   Gebied [2]
   Gebied Datum      `Som vangtuigen` `Som van Aantal`
   <chr>  <date>                <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Oost   2021-02-25              100             321.
 2 Oost   2021-03-25              100             267 
 3 Oost   2021-05-07               92             139 
 4 Oost   2021-06-02              100             245 
 5 Oost   2021-06-25               96             256.
 6 Oost   2021-07-23              100             213 
 7 Oost   2021-08-27              100             295.
 8 Oost   2021-09-24               96             335.
 9 Oost   2021-10-29               98             264 
10 Oost   2021-11-23              100             151.
# … with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CPUE_deelgebied %>% group_by(Gebied, Datum) %>% summarise(Somvangtuigen=sum(`Som vangtuigen`), SomvanAantal=sum(`Som van Aantal`))
```