# Total Sales by two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute the total sales and the end result should be product id and product type, but I keep getting only one column (product type with sales)

How can I get the product id in my end result?

```
products %>%
  filter(str_detect(product_type, regex("pizza", ignore_case = TRUE))) %>%
  inner_join(get_transactions(), by = "product_id") %>%
  group_by(product_type) %>%
  summarize(total_sales = sum(sales_value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total_sales))
```

Comment: `group_by(product_id, product_type)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of multiple columns using group\_by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708063/sum-of-multiple-columns-using-group-by-function)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Group by
Try to group by the second criterion, maybe that will solve the issue.
It is difficult to understand what you get as a result of your code. Could you add a picture?
Maybe the problem in filter setting to only one output?

Comment: If I grroup by "product id" then I will only get product id and sales. I need to see product id and type and sales.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).